# unable to run activator command with pipe sign

Tags: shell, zsh

I have a command 
activator ~run 
in zsh.

But I always got 
zsh: no such user or named directory: run

So how do I escape the pipe sign ?

Comment: This character - `~` is called "Tilde"; it is **not** the pipe character. This is the pipe character: `|`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried different ways and found I have to escape the ~ with \